# OUTPUT a DATE and Time from database TIMESTAMP PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can i convert the timestamp in database table row to 9:00AM or PM

say i have a row value from database 2016-10-14 15:08:06

the Output must be 2016-10-14 03:08 AM or PM using php

```
2016-10-14 03:08 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example we have time stamp at below variable

```
$t="1512314221";
```

use Date function to convert it to date time format :

```
echo Date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$t); //output 2017-03-13 15:17:01
```

also you can append these strings to date format :

- F    A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March
- m    Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through 12
- M    A short textual representation of a month, three letters    Jan
  through Dec
- l (lowercase 'L')    A full textual representation of the day of the
  week Sunday through Saturday
- D    A textual representation of a day, three letters    Mon through Sun
- g    12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 1 through 12
- G    24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros 0 through 23
- h    12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros    01 through 12

Comment: thanks man but the above answer gets the right question for me =) also output PM and AM..still thank you for the cool answer =)

Comment: for AM and PM just add A or a for date function first parameter as date format 
for example Y/m/d H:i A it will output 2017/03/13 15:17 PM
your well come : )  @cdccatz

Comment: thanks man but the above answer gets the right answer for my question  =) it also output PM and AM..still thank you for the cool answer =)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it, is with [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$dt = new DateTime( '2016-10-14 15:08:06' );
echo $dt->format( 'Y-m-d h:i A' );
```

See [`date()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) for the available formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

Write if condition to check if your datetime is in AM interval (check only hours). If true echo AM else echo PM.